# Is it possible to load a same page in multiple iframes?

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

So i have 2 pages on same domain, one is registration.html and index.html.

Registration has a registration form with a textbox, a checkbox and a submit button.

What i want is having 3 iframes on the main page that will focus those 3 element.

Iframe 1 focuses the textbox
Iframe 2 the checkbox
Iframe 3 submit button.

So is it possible to load it in a way that those 3 elements are connected? 
So when i enter my text, check the checkbox and click submit on iframe 3 it will register all that stuff?

Second question is do i need to align those elements as they are in the original form, or i can make my own positioning and they will still focus elements and the inputs will still be connected?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It is expected that you at least attempt to code this for yourself. Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. I would suggest that you do some additional research, either via Google or by searching SO, make an attempt and. if you still have trouble, come back with **your code** and explain what you have tried and why it did not work.

Comment: Hi, i just want to ask, instead of loading from different pages, why don't u put the 3 elements in the same page ?

Comment: Im using google+ comment plugin, and I want to redesign it so it suites my sites design. I will still use the same text as its on the original but want to change it completely..